# Invert text color on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to invert a black text while hovering it with a custom -black- cursor.
This GIF demonstrates the effect:

[image]

Couldn't wrap my head around to make this work with CSS & JS. Some combination with mix-blend-modes, clipping masks, pseudo elements and filters I guess.

The following code makes the cursor white but doesn't alow the black text to be turned white. Sounds abstract? Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/danoszz/pen/XEQVNB).

```js
// All creds go to https://murmure.me 

const cursor = $(".cursor"),
      body = $("body"),
      slider = $(".slider"),
      nav = $(".nav"),
      fail = $(".fail"),
      invert = $(".invert"),
      nav_open_menu = $(".navopen"),
      wwidth = $(window).width(),
      wheight = $(window).height(),
             
cursorMove = function() {
  var e, n;
  return (
    body.addClass("cursor-on"),
    cursor.css({
      transform: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, " + wwidth / 2 + ", " + wheight / 2 + ")"
    }),
    (e = wheight / 2),
    (n = 0.65 * wwidth / 2),
    n > e ? e : n,
    $(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
      var n, t;
      if (
        ((window.x = e.clientX),
        (window.y = e.clientY),
        cursor.css({
          transform: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, " + x + ", " + y + ")"
        }),
        !nav.hasClass("overlay-visible"))
      )
        return (
          (n = Math.floor((x - 60) / 5)),
          (t = Math.floor((y - 60) / 5)),
          n < 20 && t < 20
            ? nav_open_menu.addClass("magnetize").css({
                transform: "scale(1.3) translate3d(" + n + "px, " + t + "px, 0)"
              })
            : nav_open_menu.removeClass("magnetize").attr("style", "")
        );
    })
  );
};
cursorBind = function() {
    var e, n, t;
    if (
      ((n = cursor.find("span")).removeClass("link external new"),
      (e = $(".focus")),
      (t = $(".slack")),
      $(window).on({
        mouseenter: function() {
          return n.removeClass("off");
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          return n.addClass("off");
        }
      }),
      $("a, button, .cursor-link, .sort-listing th").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
          var e;
          return (
            (e = $(this).hasClass("external") ? "link external" : "link"),
            n.addClass(e)
          );
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          return n.removeClass("link external");
        }
      }),
      $("h1").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
          var e;
          return (
            (e = $(this).hasClass("external") ? "invert external" : "invert"),
            n.addClass(e)
          );
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          return n.removeClass("invert external");
        }
      }),
      e.length &&
        e.find("a").on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            return n.addClass("new");
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
            return n.removeClass("new");
          }
        }),
      slider.length &&
        slider.on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            var e;
            return (
              (e = $(this).hasClass("full") ? "click" : "drag"), n.addClass(e)
            );
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
            return n.removeClass("drag click");
          }
        }),
      t.length &&
        t.on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            return n.addClass("light");
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
            return n.removeClass("light");
          }
        }),
      fail.length)
    )
      return fail.on({
        mouseover: function() {
          return n.addClass("relol");
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          return n.removeClass("relol");
        }
      });
  };

cursorMove();
cursorBind();
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 9vw;
}
 

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  line-height: 1.5;
 /* System stack font-family mentioned by @wooorm */
  font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Open Sans, sans-serif;
}
 .cursor-on {
  cursor: none;
}
 .cursor-on * {
  cursor: none;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: -1rem;
  left: -1rem;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span {
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background: #f8e71c;
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.off {
  transform: scale(0);
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.link {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: #0000ed;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.link.external:after {
  content: "↗";
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 0.6em;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.light {
  background: #fff;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.drag, .cursor-on .cursor > span.click, .cursor-on .cursor > span.relol, .cursor-on .cursor > span.new {
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.drag:after, .cursor-on .cursor > span.click:after, .cursor-on .cursor > span.relol:after, .cursor-on .cursor > span.new:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  white-space: pre;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: calc((2rem / 2) - 2.5px);
  color: #000;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.drag:after {
  content: "play";
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.click:after {
  content: "click\A click";
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.relol:after {
  content: "click\A me";
  padding-top: calc((2rem / 2) - 5px);
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.new:after {
  content: "new\A new";
}
 .cursor-on:active .cursor > span {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
 .cursor-on:active .cursor > span.link {
  transform: scale(1);
}
 .cursor-on:active .cursor > span.drag, .cursor-on:active .cursor > span.click, .cursor-on:active .cursor > span.relol, .cursor-on:active .cursor > span.new {
  transform: scale(2);
}
 .grid {
  background-color: #fff;
}
 .grid--column--item {
  background-color: #000;
}
 .grid--column.sticky .grid--column--item {
  border-color: #000;
}


.cursor-on .cursor > span {
  background: black;
}
 .cursor-on .cursor > span.invert {
  transform: scale(2.5);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="invert">Work</h1>


<div class="cursor" >
  <span class="off"></span>
 </div>
```

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
filter: invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(2);
```

I've setup a [playground on Codepen](https://codepen.io/danoszz/pen/XEQVNB) to mess around with, but didn't found a solution yet.

How could this hover effect be recreated with CSS and Javascript?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is an idea using `clip-path`. The trick is to duplicate the text to have two layers above each other with different text color then I reveal the top one using the `clip-path` that I adjust with the move of the mouse.

```js
var h =document.querySelector('h1');
var p= h.getBoundingClientRect();
var c= document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  /*Adjust the cursor position*/
  c.style.left=e.clientX+'px';
  c.style.top=e.clientY+'px';
  /*Adjust the clip-path*/
  h.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX-p.top)+'px');
  h.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY-p.left)+'px');
}
```

```css
body {
  cursor:none;
}
h1 {
  color: #000;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
h1:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:attr(data-text);
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  clip-path: circle(20px at var(--x,-100%) var(--y,-100%));
}
.cursor {
  position:fixed;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="WORK">WORK</h1>

<span class="cursor"></span>
```

Here is Another idea using `radial-gradient` and without duplicating the text that can work with multiple elements at the same time:

```js
document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX)+'px');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY)+'px');
}
```

```css
body {
  cursor:none;
}

.mask {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle 20px 
                    at var(--x,0) var(--y,0), 
                    #fff 99%,black 100%) 
                    fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
html::before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:var(--y,0);
  left:var(--x,0);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="mask">WORK</h1>
<p class="mask">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis risus sapien. Maecenas dui orci, blandit et commodo eget, egestas quis odio. Donec eu tortor turpis. Aliquam convallis et nisi ut varius. Proin sapien erat, auctor in efficitur vel, efficitur sit amet justo. In pretium iaculis tempus. Vivamus congue</p>

<p class="mask">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis risus sapien. Maecenas dui orci, blandit et commodo eget, egestas quis odio. Donec eu tortor turpis. Aliquam convallis et nisi ut varius. Proin sapien erat, auctor in efficitur vel, efficitur sit amet justo. In pretium iaculis tempus. Vivamus congue</p>
```

Related question with similar ideas: [Stacking circles produces a black bar on border radius](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54674595/8620333)

Comment: Great thanks! How could this be working when the cursor is scaling and moved by a transform: matrix in the original JS code? https://codepen.io/danoszz/pen/GxreBV

Comment: @danoszz as you can see in my code, the cursor and the circle used with clip-path or radial gradient have the same dimension ... so if you scale the cirlce you need to change the dimension to make them match

Answer (score 7):

Made a solution using `mix-blend-mode: difference;` for the `.cursor`.

The advantage is - we don't need to add any classes or javascript to all elements that we are hovering with our circle-mouse over.

The disadvantage is - this solution less stable due to `mix-blend-mode` is a bit raw technology. It requires to set `height` in `body` and `html`, and strict `background-color` for `body`.

The part with `.cursor` CSS and JavaScript - I partly borrowed form the solution of @Temani Afif. Thank you and hope you don't mind, because it's pointless to try to write it better. But i added `+window.scrollX` and `+window.scrollY` for correct `.cursor` work while scrolling.

More about `mix-blend-mode` you cay read here https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

```js
document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--x', (e.clientX+window.scrollX) + 'px');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--y', (e.clientY+window.scrollY) + 'px');
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%; /* requires for stable body height */
}

body {
  min-height: 100%; /* requires for 'mix-blend-mode' */
  cursor: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff; /* requires for 'mix-blend-mode' */
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: var(--y, 0);
  left: var(--x, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<h1>WORK</h1>
<span class="cursor"></span>
```