# Blend text as white over image

Tags: css

I am trying to reproduce the effect of this page : http://www.saramarandi.com/ .

I want that when an image is over a black text, the text blends into white.

I have tried combinations of mix-blend-mode, color, text-clip without any success.

Comment: can you provide what you have done so far?

Comment: That specific effect, together with the image under the cursor seems done using WebGL

Comment: You might get some ideas here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793312/invert-text-color-on-mouse-hover/49793884#49793884