# How can I make a circular clip-mask that follows the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clip-path

I have a webpage that contains korean text and I would like to make it so that there is a circular clip-mask that follows the cursor so that when the clip-mask is over the korean text, the english translation is revealed underneath.  I have some code so far, but I'm not sure how to get the whole thing working.  How might I achieve this? An example of this effect is [here](https://www.kikk.be/2018/en/home), but I'm not sure how they got the effect.
There is also an error in the code, and I'm not sure what it is.

Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('.hero').mousemove(function(e){
     var rXP = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft-$(this).width()/2);
     var rYP = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop-$(this).height()/2);
     $('.hero').css('text-shadow', +rYP/10+'px '+rXP/80+'px rgba(227,6,19,.8), '+rYP/8+'px '+rXP/60+'px rgba(255,237,0,1), '+rXP/70+'px '+rYP/12+'px rgba(0,159,227,.7)');
   });
    $('.hiddenhero').mousemove(function(e){
     var rXP = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft-$(this).width()/2);
     var rYP = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop-$(this).height()/2);
     $('.hiddenhero').css('text-shadow', +rYP/10+'px '+rXP/80+'px rgba(227,6,19,.8), '+rYP/8+'px '+rXP/60+'px rgba(255,237,0,1), '+rXP/70+'px '+rYP/12+'px rgba(0,159,227,.7)');
   });
});

window.onload = function(){
               var bsDiv = document.getElementById("herocircle");
               var x, y;
               window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
                   x = event.clientX;
                   y = event.clientY;                    
                   if ( typeof x !== 'undefined' ){
                       bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                       bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                   }
               }, false);
           }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans');

html {
  align-items: center;
  background: #fcf8f2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.herocontainer {
  height: 1920px;
  width: 1080px;
  clip-path: url(#heroclip);
}
.hero {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Black Han Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  transform: skew(-7deg, -7deg);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
}
.herop {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>History</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <defs>
    <svg>
      <clipPath id="heroclip">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="125" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent"/>
      </clipPath>
    </svg>   
  </defs> 
  <div id="herocontainer">
      <div class="hero">
        <p class="herop">대한민국</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this may give you some ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793312/invert-text-color-on-mouse-hover/49793884#49793884

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://history--jodastt.repl.co/ here is my result: what is wrong?

Comment: you didn't add the JS code

Comment: @TemaniAfif still doesn't work...

Comment: your are almost good, the JS is working fine but the values aren't correct, will try to figure out the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have it partially working, but the circle has been moved up and right relative to the cursor.  Any idea why?

Comment: I am working on it, will give you the good code soon ;)

Comment: here is : https://jsfiddle.net/y9wx4oa6/ .. the transform was making the thing not easy

Comment: @TemaniAfif nice, it works, but why is it still offset?  I can't figure out why.

Comment: because of the skew, the calculation is done before the skew and since the skew is a visual effect it will be done after the calculation ... so you may need to ajdust the Y a bit to get the correct value but it will be tricky to do

Comment: Is there any way to do the skew before the calculation? @TemaniAfif