# Backdrop-filter on a custom cursor?

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering: Can I apply backdrop-filter:invert on a cursor in css?

So let's say I have a custom cursor (png, svg...) and I want it to always be the inverse color of whatever the background is.

(On white b.g. it would show as black, on blue b.g. it would be the opposite color, and also on a photo, it could appear as "negative".)

Does someone know how could this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Implement your own cursor, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49793312/8620333

Comment: This is exactly how I meant it visually! :) But as the the "cursor" is a span in this case, I cannot really click, or use other hover actions, because the span is "in the way".

Comment: you can add `pointer-events:none` to the span and you can click/hover

Comment: True, this works well, thank you! :)